# AntiX 17.4 Full, how to properly install Xfce with everything 100% working

Tags: linux, xfce, antix

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg x11-xserver-utils xfonts-base x11-utils lightdm lightdm-gtk-greeter xfce4 xfce4-goodies -y --allow-unauthenticated
```

Reboot.  The above command works.. but XFCE isn't 100% working:

[image]
[image]

<s>Icons are missing,</s> Icons are restored by Settings>Appearance>Pick Icons.  In the 'Settings' there is alot of applications missing.  Here are a few applications missing:  Under Hardware:  Power Manager, Bluetooth, Removable drives and media.  Under System:  Firewall. Here is what a normal 'Settings' screen looks like (this is from a diff distro but you get the point):

[image]

Also users screen is missing, heres what happens when you click on it:

[image]

I tried:

```
sudo apt-get install mugshot
```

The output says:

```
Writing Menu:  fluxbox
Writing Menu:  icewm
Writing Menu:  jwm
```

But no xfce.

**So how do I do install XFCE on AntiX Full where everything works 100%?**  If you want to post an answer for "AntiX core" by all means please do, that would probably be better practice anyway.

Comment: @K7AAY, Thank you for the enlightenment, my question is phrased as best as I can, if you can see an improvement please let me know.  0xSheepdog, Thank you for your comment as well good sir.

Comment: You can try to ask [here](https://forum.xfce.org/index.php)

Comment: Yes sir, will do.  Thank you, much appreciated.  If I find an answer I will post on here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run these commands after a fresh install:

```
sudo apt-get update -y;sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg x11-xserver-utils xfonts-base x11-utils lightdm lightdm-gtk-greeter xfce4 xfce4-goodies xfce4-power-manager xfce4-power-manager-plugins xfce4-taskmanager blueman bluez-tools pulseaudio pulseaudio-module-bluetooth pavucontrol -y --allow-unauthenticated
```

---

```
mkdir ~/.config/autostart;touch ~/.config/autostart/wicdstart.desktop;echo -e '[Desktop Entry]\nEncoding=UTF-8\nVersion=0.9.4\nType=Application\nName=wicdstart\nComment=\nExec=gksu "/bin/wicdstart.sh"\nOnlyShowIn=XFCE;\nStartupNotify=false\nTerminal=false\nHidden=false' > ~/.config/autostart/wicdstart.desktop;echo "%users ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/wicdstart.sh" >> /etc/sudoers.d/antixers;touch ~/.config/autostart/wicd-tray.desktop;rm -rf /etc/xdg/autostart/wicd-tray.desktop;echo -e "/usr/bin/python -O /usr/share/wicd/daemon/wicd-daemon.py\nwicd-gtk --tray" > /bin/wicdstart.sh;chmod +x /bin/wicdstart.sh
```

Reboot and your done.

As far as missing icons, I'm not sure if the XFCE guys fixed this or what, but after you run the above command, the icons are fine.

For the following Apps/packages:

**Firewall:**

antiX has their own firewall.  Works just fine.

**Power Manager:**

Included in the command above and everything works.

**Bluetooth:**

Included in the command above and everything works.  [ALSA](https://www.alsa-project.org/wiki/Main_Page) is the default sound system in antiX.  I couldn't figure out how to pull up a pleasant looking bluetooth GUI with ALSA (command prompt GUI options).  I used blueman for the bluetooth manager, which uses pulseaudio.  I'm going to guess that ALSA is probably way more efficient than pulseaudio.  If thats true and I could get a plesant GUI bluetooth with ALSA, I would have used it.  pulseaudio works well and provides pleasant/modern GUI.

**Removable drives and media:**

This question is answered by [ToZ](https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?pid=52236#p52236).  You can probably apply the same method to replace any missing icons you have under Settings.

**mugshot:**

Who cares?  mugshot only lets you add a picture/user info to a user.  It doesn't actually add/edit/remove users.  antiX User Manager is for managing users.  In whiskermenu, you should **disable mugshot**:  whiskermenu Properties>Commands Tab>Uncheck 'Edit Profile'.  Now if they try to click, nothing happens.

When trying to get mugshot to work with this command:

```
sudo apt-get install mugshot accountsservice -y;
```

accountsservice messes up your user login for XFCE in antiX. What happens is: You get to the login screen and login with your user. It then takes you back to the login screen.  Endless Loop.  So it forces you to login as root.

**Other Credits:**

- I got a lot of the install commands from youtuber **runwiththedolphin**.
- **ToZ** from forum.xfce.org for his guidance.  If he wouldn't have responded to my [post](https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?pid=52226#p52226), I probably wouldn't have spent the time to come up with this answer.

**Other Thoughts:**

- Would be cool to use SLiM instead of lightdm.  If you do this command:

  sudo dpkg-reconfigure slim

you can peacefully switch from XFCE to the default desktop environment that comes with antiX

- Maybe uninstall/disable ALSA?  Or maybe find a pleasant GUI bluetooth manager for ALSA.
- antiX is great, but the native lockscreen on 17.4 is not your normal user-friendly lockscreen. i3lock is a decent answer to this.  You have to make sure i3lock executes fast enough to not be a security risk last time I checked.  I personally couldn't get i3 to be more integrated with the system.  Like maybe the OS could wait for i3lock lockscreen before doing anything else.
- **259MB of memory used** after all this is said and done.  CPU idles at 0%. 
  antiX is super efficient.